# Where is the right place to put jquery plugin default settings in the code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello
I am writing some jquery usefuls plugins, but I am asking where should I put the defaults settings object in the code.  example Here i put them inside the init method:

```
(function($)
{
    var methods =
    {
        init : function(options)
        {
            var settings = {
                      'images3dPath' : '',
                      'imagesZoomPath':'',
                               ..................
                };
```

Or I should put them at the top of the plugin:

```
(function($)
{
var settings = {
    'images3dPath' : '',
    'imagesZoomPath':'',
      ..................
    };
    var methods =
    {
        init : function(options)
        {
```

In this moment I am using the first solution, but I am not sure of that. Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to make you default settings on the same level as your function that takes `options` so that there a local variable unique to each call of your plugin rather then a static global list of settings.

It's just my `options` function tends to be an outer one.

I have

```
var globalDefaults = { ... };
var methods = {};
methods.init = function(options) {
    ...
    var settings = { ... };
    $.extend(true, settings, options);
    ...
};
```